# C# Events in a tic tac toe game

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am new in coding and atm trying to understand events what is an annoying stage but super important I guess. I just made a tic tac toe game and it is working but not really "beautiful" coded. I really have problems in using the events. well I am reading 3 different books, google is my best friend and I guess I red all the StackOverflow posts about events but the bulb in my head is never shining :P so I will give you boys a part of my code and I added some comments for the understanding:

```
      /*I have 9 buttons(3x3) which are the play field */ 
    private void Feld1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // in my game each player have 1 Radiobutton so they check a RButton and then it's their turn
        if (Player1RButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            // i dont wanted to use "X" or "O" so i chose the colors green and yellow
            Feld1.Background = Brushes.Green;
            // Feld1G is for example that Player1 (green) is "owning" this 
            // field/button so i can later check who won the game
            Feld1G = 1;
            Feld1Y = 0;

        }
        if (Player2RButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            //here is the same thing happening like in the example of green
            Feld1.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            Feld1Y = 1;
            Feld1G = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Feld2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Player1RButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            Feld2.Background = Brushes.Green;
            Feld2G = 1;
            Feld2Y = 0;
        }
        if (Player2RButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            Feld2.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            Feld2Y = 1;
            Feld2G = 0;
        }
    }
```

here is an example how the ui looks like:[tic tac toe exampe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EBjf.png)

now what I would like to do in my words cause I don't know how to code it:

// I have no idea if this is the right start

```
public void OnClick (EventArgs e)
    {
       /* now I guess here have to happen something like this, for example, field9 was clicked and radiobutton2 is checked: know that button9 have been clicked know radiobutton is checked and now brush (this.button?)  button/field9 and set Feld9Y=1; 
    }
```

*/

I want to make it a bit more clearly here: I want all the functions run from the method above and not in each button event for itself

so my questions: 
1. what do I have to do to make this work the way i explained above to make 1 method for all of my buttons

2. and it would be great if you boys could make a good story why I have to use it this way and how it works so a brainless ape like me can understand the event stuff and the bulb will finally shine bright like a diamond :P

Edit:here is the link for my whole code:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164462/c-events-in-a-tic-tac-toe-game

Comment: You have logic spread among 9 click event handlers and you are thinking to refactor it? Post complete working code to [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe+c%23).

Comment: okay i will but i have to wait 40 min so i can send another question there. i will link that question as well so you can see my whole code

Comment: As an aside, to get more responses you should refrain from using exclusive language like boys/guys in your requests.

Comment: thanks i will change this in my future questions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example to get you started. I only implemented changing the background and nothing more.

Below is the xaml. I set up a very simple board with 9 regular buttons and 2 radio buttons. I did not implement anything else.

```
    <Grid x:Name="board">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Button"/>
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="playerOneRadioButton" 
                 IsChecked="True"
                 Content="Player 1"
                 Grid.Column="3"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="10,10,0,0"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="playerTwoRadioButton"
                 Content="Player 2"
                 Grid.Column="3"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="10,30,0,0"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Below is the code behind.
I hooked up each buttons click event to point to the Button_Click method.
In that method I first cast the sender to type Button. I then change the background color of the button to either yellow or green.

```
 public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow( )
    {
        InitializeComponent( );

        // Iterate through all of the child elements
        // contained in the Grid control which I named "board".
        foreach( var control in board.Children.OfType<Button>( ) )
        {
            // Hook up the event handler of each button.
            control.Click += Button_Click;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        // Safe cast the sender to type Button.
        var button = sender as Button;
        if( button == null ) return;

        // Change the background color of the button
        // yellow or green based on which radio button
        // is checked.
        button.Background = playerOneRadioButton.IsChecked.Value ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Yellow;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
**Question 1:** The Grid which I have on the design surface is named "board". Children is a property of the Grid control. All child elements (elements that reside inside of the grid, like the buttons) are added to the Children property of the grid control. The Children property is a collection, or you could say a list, of all child elements that reside in the grid control. I loop through each child control in the grid that is of type button.

**Question 2:** The ?: is called a ternary operator. It is used for writing a conditional statement (an if statement). You can also write it as follows:

```
if( playerOneRadioButton.IsChecked.Value ) 
{
    button.Background = Brushes.Green;
}
else 
{
    button.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
}
```

**Question 3:** I'm currently casting the object sender to type button using whats called a "safe cast". In other words, if the cast fails (say sender wasn't a button and was some other control instead) then null is returned. I check for this null condition to ensure that the cast was successful. If the button variable is null then the cast was not successful and I want to exit (return) out of that method. No code below the

```
if(button == null) return;
```

will execute.

Comment: This is by no means perfect. For example the same button can be selected twice during a match. This should be prevented. I challenge you to find a way to only allow a button to be selected once per match. In other words, if player 1 selects the first button, player 2 should be prevented from also selecting the first button.

Comment: thanks this is what i was looking for can you please explain the: in board.Children    >children< thing and what does the Is.Checked.Value >?< questionmark do/is for? oh and the line : if(button == null) return; then i am happy i guess ;) i have to get rid of my old button events then it should work and i will accept your answer

Comment: yeah i was thinking about something like that as well i will try to implement something like that after my code is working again :D

Comment: awesome @WBuck you really helped me a lot thanks for your time and work

Answer (score 0):

The single method you want to use should look like this:

```
private void Feld_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentButton = (Button)sender;

    if (Player1RButton.IsChecked == true)
    {
        currentButton.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
}
```

Add this as `OnClick` handler for all the buttons.

From there you can calculate the `Feld` color whenever you need it, by accessing the `Background` property in a separate method.

Comment: int the line var current button = (button)object;<-- this object is a invalid expression

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r: it should be `var currentButton = (button)sender;`

Comment: now i can start the programm but it dont brushes the buttons anymore